# Opening Several UIDocuments in Succession and Waiting for Them to Finish

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidocument

I'm having trouble getting my head around the way UIDocuments open asynchronously. I have a series of UIDocuments that the user has created. When the user presses a button I need to open some of the documents, pull some strings from them, and concatenate the strings into a new file.

I have an array that keeps track of which documents need to be opened. My thought was that I should loop through the array, open each document, and append its contents to an `NSMutableString`. The problem is that `openWithCompletionHandler` does its work asynchronously, so the loop marches ahead and finishes, returning an empty string, before the documents have been opened (and closed again).

Here's a little bit of code:

```
__block NSMutableString *combinedString;

for (entryClass *entry in documentList)
{
    MyDocumentClass *document = [[MyDocumentClass alloc] initWithFileURL:[entry fileURL]];

    if ([document documentState] & UIDocumentStateClosed) {
        [document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {

            if (success) {
                [combinedString appendString:[document documentBody]];
            }

            [document closeWithCompletionHandler:nil];
        }];
    }
}

NSLog(@"Combined String: %@", combinedString);
```

Naturally what happens is that `combinedString` comes back empty because the loop finishes while the documents are opening in the background. I could move the document handling to its own method that returns a string but I think this will still return before the document is read. I'll presumably have to put up a progress indicator and make user wait--that's probably okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with dispatch groups. See the sections "Groups" and "Using dispatch_group_t with Existing API" at [Low-Level Concurrency APIs](http://www.objc.io/issue-2/low-level-concurrency-apis.html).

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do something very similar and rather than delving into low level functions I opened the document with `openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:display:completionHandler:`.  Because it passes the opened document to the `completionHandler` you can do the work to extract the data from the document  and then close it in the `completionHandler` block.

This assumes that you don't care what order the documents will write their data to the string, because in theory the `completionHandlers` for the different document could be run in any order.